# Non-primary embedded database schema not being initiliazed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot (`1.5.10.RELEASE`) application that uses 2 embedded databases. This two databases are defined equally but one's defined on the application itself and one's defined on a custom autoconfiguration class that's on an imported JAR; yet only the one flagged as `@Primary` (the one on the application) gets the schema initialized.

This is the current definition for both datasources:

Primary, on the application:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {    

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSourceProperties firstProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        return firstProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JdbcTemplate firstTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(firstDataSource());
    }
}
```

On the autoconfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "second.datasource.url")
public class SecondDataSourceAutoconfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties secondProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
         return secondProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate secondJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }
}
```

And my application.yml fills the properties:

```
first:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:firstdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
second:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:seconddb
        platform: h2
```

My resources folder contains both a `schema.sql` that's executed on `firstdb` and a `schema-h2.sql` which should get executed on `seconddb` but does not. I tried playing around with the `datasource.schema` and `datasource.initialize` properties, switching the script names and the platform property to the first datasource (in that case, the `schema-h2.sql` gets executed on `firstdb`, but nothing on the `seconddb`) and changing the embedded database provider to HSQLDB; but can't get the schema for the non-primary in-memory DB initialized anyhow.